# Throw-in directly into the goal

Tags: football, trivia

At the international playing level, has anyone ever thrown the ball directly into the goal, from a throw-in?  Directly meaning, without touching a member from either team, including the goalie.  It does not matter if it touches the ground first.

Comment: Do you mean without touching any player or ground?

Comment: Yes.  Without touching either team, or the goalie.  The ground would be acceptable.

Comment: PSA: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/919/are-questions-specifically-asking-about-trivial-illegal-situations-without-being). Everyone is also reminded of the [Code of Conduct](https://sports.stackexchange.com/conduct) - it is possible to disagree without being rude.

Comment: Most players probably know that you can not score from a throw in though...

Comment: It happened [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_zPxzbBV4c). I don't know the exact references of this situation, but considering the joy of the scorer, it seems that the goal has been accepted... but it souldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it happened the 2 october 2014 in a [Europa League game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_UEFA_Europa_League_group_stage#Feyenoord_v_Standard_Li%C3%A8ge) between Feyenoord and Standard Liege (2-1).

> It was officially credited to defender Sven van Beek (wearing 22), but it looked as though it was scored directly from the throw by Miquel Nelom.

It seems the referee judged that the ball touched someone, even it didn't.

[Source](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2779295/Feyenoord-score-incredible-goal-straight-throw-against-Standard-Liege.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I do appreciate this answer.  I was hoping to find an instance where it was not presumed to have gone off another player.  I'll give it a little time.  If no one comes to the dance, the cred is yours.